# If we select a random integer number of the set $[1000000]$ what is the probability of the number selected contains the digit $5$?

Tags: probability

If we select a random integer number of the set $[1000000]$ what is the probability of the number selected contains the digit $5$?

**My work:**

We know the sample space $S:$"The set of number of 1 to 1000000" and $|S|=1000000$

Let $E$ the event such that $E:$"The set of number contains the digit 5 in $[1000000]$" We need calculate $|E|$.

I know in $[100]$ we have $5,15,25,35,45,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,65,75,85,95$ then we have 19 numbers contains the digit $5$ in the set $[100]$

Then in $[1000]-[500]$ we have 171 numbers have the digit 5. this implies [1000] have 271 number contains the digit 5.

.
.
.

Following the previous reasoning we have to $[10000]$ have 3439 number contains the digit 5.

Then,  $[100000]$have 40951 number contains the digit 5.

Moreover, $[1000000]$ have 468559 number contain the digit 5.

In consequence the probability of we pick a digit contain the number 5 in the set $[1000000]$ is 0.468

Is correct this?

How else could obtain $|E|$?

Thanks

Comment: I assume you mean $1$ to $1000000$?

Comment: Yes is that @Remy

Comment: Among the integers $\{0,1,2,3,\dots,999999\}$ there are $9^6$ numbers without any $5$'s.  Can you see why?  Adjusting and looking instead at $\{1,2,3,\dots,1000000\}$ it remains $9^6$ don't have a $5$.

Comment: I think you take the complement, no? @JMoravitz

Comment: Temporarily allow leading zeroes to be considered and count how many six-digit strings there are using digits $\{0,1,2,3,4,6,7,8,9\}$.  Apply [rule of product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product) with the steps "pick the first digit", "pick the second digit", etc...

Comment: In the end, the probability is $\frac{10^6-9^6}{10^6}$ which is indeed $\frac{468559}{1000000}$ as you correctly calculated.  Using rule of product and using complements though gives the answer almost instantly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Notice that $P(\text{contains 5})=1-P(\text{doesn't contain 5})$. The latter is easily calculated by calculating the probabilities that each individual digit is not 5. Hence,

$$
\begin{align}
P(\text{doesn't contain 5})&=\left(\frac{9}{10}\right)^6\\
&=\frac{531441}{1000000}
\end{align}
$$
and
$$
\begin{align}
P(\text{contains 5})&=1-P(\text{doesn't contain 5})\\
&=1-\frac{531441}{1000000}\\
&=\frac{468559}{1000000}
\end{align}
$$
which corresponds with the answer you got.